# storing string in variable fails to work in `early-init.el`

Tags: init-file, variables

Putting the following code in my `early-init.el` causes my emacs not to startup.

```
(require 'cl-lib)

(defvar void-initial-frame-font
  (cl-find-if (lambda (font) (find-font (font-spec :name font)))
          (list "Victor Mono-19" "Anonymous-Pro-19"))
  "Font for initial frame.")

(push (cons 'font void-initial-frame-font) default-frame-alist)
```

The form `(cl-find-if ...)` evaluates to "Victor Mono-19". Thus `void-initial-frame-font` is "Victor Mono-19".

When I replace the variable `void-initial-frame-font` in the push form with what it should evaluate to, my emacs config starts up successfully with the frame font being "Victor Mono-19" as I would expect.

```
(require 'cl-lib)

(defvar void-initial-frame-font
  (cl-find-if (lambda (font) (find-font (font-spec :name font)))
          (list "Victor Mono-19" "Anonymous-Pro-19"))
  "Font for initial frame.")

;; replaced `void-initial-frame-font` with what it should evaluate to
(push (cons 'font "Victor Mono-19") default-frame-alist)
```

For fun, I tried to see if let binding the variable font would work, but it did not. The following form also causes my emacs to fail to start.

```
(require 'cl-lib)

(let ((font (cl-find-if (lambda (font) (find-font (font-spec :name font)))
            (list "Victor Mono-19" "Anonymous-Pro-19"))))
  (push (cons 'font font) default-frame-alist))
```

Why can't I store the result of evaluating the `(cl-find-if ...)` form `early-init.el`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find-font is a built-in function in ‘C source code’.

(find-font FONT-SPEC &optional FRAME)

  Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 23.1.

Return a font-entity matching with FONT-SPEC on the current frame.
Optional 2nd argument FRAME, if non-nil, specifies the target frame.
```

I think you'll find that either there is no "current frame" during early init, or else that it's not a frame which is useful  for this purpose.

Comment: But why then does it not generate an error in my second example? I still call `find-font`. The only difference is I don't set it to the variable. Does it just return something that's not read correctly by `default-frame-alist` before the frame is created?

Comment: `find-font` will be returning `nil`.  If you don't use the return value, there's no issue.  I suspect you were creating an invalid entry for `default-frame-alist` when you used the nil value.

Comment: You can easily test what's happening by using something *other* than `default-frame-alist` (e.g. defvar a custom alist with default value nil and substitute that), and then inspect that after starting Emacs.